# Get data from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is working for only one table. When I click submit, I can save the data from the current displayed table.

But what I actually want is to save the data from all the tables (I know there's only one and that's the problem I think, because I use the same table and I just empty the body).

Basically I want to submit the data from all the tables in the selected (DDA,MTG,SAV) and also persist that saved data, for example if I change a value on DDA table, when I select another table and DDA again it should show my changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var types = [];
    var amountOfDayEnds = 4;
    var table;

    function DisplayTable() {
        var data = "";
        //Table
        $('.dataTableBody').empty();
  
        for(var i=1;i<=amountOfDayEnds;i++) {
            data += '<tr align="center">';
            data += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
            $.each(types, function (index, value) {
                data += '<td>' + '<input class="text-center amountOfAccounts" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="500" name="dataAccounts[]" data-error="Please, insert a value"  required></td>'
            });
            data += '</tr>';
        }
        $('.dataTableBody').append(data);
    }

    DisplayTable();


//Repeat the value for all rows in Clients Table
    $('.repeatForAll').change(function () {
        var number = $('.repeatForAll').val();
        $('.amountOfClients').val(number);
    });

    //$('#page2').validator();


    //create the interdepent selectors
    function initSelectors(){
        // next 2 statements should generate error message, see console
        MAIN.createRelatedSelector();
        MAIN.createRelatedSelector(document.querySelector('#cls') );

        //countries
        MAIN.createRelatedSelector
        ( document.querySelector('#cls')           // from select element
            ,document.querySelector('#group')      // to select element
            ,{                                               // values object
                Deposit: ['DDA','SAV'],
                Loan: ['MTG'],
            }
            ,function(a,b){return a>b ? 1 : a<b ? -1 : 0;}   // sort method
        );
    }

//create MAIN namespace
    (function(ns){ // don't pollute the global namespace

        function create(from, to, obj, srt){
            if (!from) {
                throw CreationError('create: parameter selector [from] missing');
            }
            if (!to) {
                throw CreationError('create: parameter related selector [to] missing');
            }
            if (!obj) {
                throw CreationError('create: related filter definition object [obj] missing');
            }

            //retrieve all options from obj and add it
            obj.all = (function(o){
                var a = [];
                for (var l in o) {
                    a = /array/i.test (o[l].constructor) ? a.concat(o[l]) : a;
                }
                return a.sort(srt);
            }(obj));
            // initialize and populate to-selector with all
            populator.call( from
                ,null
                ,to
                ,obj
                ,srt
            );

            // assign handler
            from.onchange = populator;

            function initStatics(fn,obj){
                for (var l in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(l)){
                        fn[l] = obj[l];
                    }
                }
                fn.initialized = true;
            }

            function populator(e, relatedto, obj, srt){
                // set pseudo statics
                var self = populator;
                if (!self.initialized) {
                    initStatics(self,{optselects:obj,optselectsall:obj.all,relatedTo:relatedto,sorter:srt || false});
                }

                if (!self.relatedTo){
                    throw 'not related to a selector';
                }
                // populate to-selector from filter/all
                var optsfilter = this.selectedIndex < 1
                    ? self.optselectsall
                    : self.optselects[this.options[this.selectedIndex].firstChild.nodeValue]
                    ,cselect = self.relatedTo
                    ,opts = cselect.options;
                if (self.sorter) optsfilter.sort(self.sorter);
                opts.length = 0;
                for (var i=0;i<optsfilter.length;i+=1){
                    opts[i] = new Option(optsfilter[i],optsfilter[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        // custom Error
        function CreationError(mssg){
            return {name:'CreationError',message:mssg};
        }

        // return the create method with some error handling
        window[ns] = {
            createRelatedSelector: function(from,to,obj,srt) {
                try {
                    if (arguments.length<1) {
                        throw CreationError('no parameters');
                    }
                    create.call(null,from,to,obj,srt);
                }
                catch(e) { console.log('createRelatedSelector ->',e.name,'\n'
                    + e.message +
                    '\ncheck parameters'); }
            }
        };
    }('MAIN'));

    //initialize
    initSelectors();

    //get account types based on group
    $('#group').change(TypesChanged);
    $('#cls').change(TypesChanged);

    function TypesChanged() {
        var columnStructure = "";
        selectedGroup = $('#group').val();

        switch (selectedGroup) {
            case "DDA":
                types = ["400","4044","4045"];
                break;
            case "SAV":
                types = ["300","310"];
                break;
            case "MTG":
                types = ["700","710"];
                break;
        }
        console.log("Selected group: " + selectedGroup + ", Types: " + types);
        $('.dataTableHead').empty();
        $('.dataTableFooter').empty();
        columnStructure += '<tr align="center">';
        columnStructure += '<th class="text-center">Day</th>';

        $.each(types, function (index, value) {
            columnStructure += '<th class="text-center">Type ' + value + '</th>';
        });
        columnStructure += '</tr>';
        $('.dataTableHead').append(columnStructure);
        $('.dataTableFooter').append(columnStructure);
        DisplayTable();
        table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
    }

    TypesChanged();


    $('#btnSubmit').click( function() {
        var data = table.$('input, select').serializeArray();
        console.log(data);
        var group = $('#group').val();
        data.push({name: 'group', value: group});
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Accounts',
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                $('#result').html("Data saved...");
                $('#result').addClass("alert alert-success");
                window.location.href = "/transactions.jsp";
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#result').html("Error...");
                $('#result').addClass("alert alert-danger");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('#btnReset').click(function () {
        $('#page3').trigger('reset');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>




 <div class="row mb-2">
                        <label>
                            Show
                            <select name="cls" id="cls">
                                <option value="All">All</option>
                                <option value="Deposit">Deposit</option>
                                <option value="Loan">Loan</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                        <label>
                            Show
                            <select name="group" id="group">
                                
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                      <div class="text-right" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-2" id="btnReset">Reset</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-2" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <!-- Example DataTables Card-->
                        <div class="card col-lg-12">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="table center-aligned-table table-striped">
                                    <table class="table center-aligned-table" id="dataTable">
                                        <thead class="dataTableHead">
                                       
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot class="dataTableFooter">
                              
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody class="dataTableBody">
                           
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: If there is only one table where does the data come from for the others you want to save? Question is confusing

Comment: Yeah I think that's the problem. It should be one table per Type but only the active should be displayed (because they have different headers). Unless there's a way to store the table data for that select and then load again. And when Submiting I need to save the data from ALL tables inside my `$('#btnSubmit').click( function()`

Comment: The data are the inputs. The data is the numbers you write there. The default value is 0.

Comment: also are you having trouble with the selector `var data = table.$('input, select').serializeArray();` ? are you saying it only works with 1 table instead of x tables?

Comment: if the data you want to save is not in the DOM or anywhere accessible idk how you could save it... Maybe instead of emptying the same table every time you create a new table and hide the old one before you show it. That way you can get all the data from each table (hidden or not) before your ajax request

Comment: My code is not implemented for many tables. I don't have any problem with my code but works only with 1 table.

Comment: What is doing the saving? Do you have an AJAX operation to a server-side endpoint?